# Can I do a timer loop and timeout for serial port communication in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm more familiar with C language and recently I've been ask to do C# for serial communication.
Below is my code for receiving data from COM port:

```
public void RxData()
{
    int i = 0;
    int Data;
    bool StartRx = false;
    int timer;

    while (true)
    {
        Data = sp.ReadByte();
        if (Data == 0x01)
        {
            StartRx = true;
        }
        if (StartRx == true)
        {
            RxBuffer[i++] = Data;
        }
        if (Data == 0x04)
        {
            RxChkSum = RxBuffer[i - 2];
            break;
        }
        timer++;
        if(timer>100) 
        {
            timer = 0;
            break;
        }
    } 
}
```

Above is the way I receive data starting with 0x01 and ends with 0x04.

I'm incrementing a timer to count til 100 and quit the while loop in case I don't receive any data. Some sort like a timeout.

But seems like the timer don't work. When I don't receive any data, my program just stuck in the while loop forever.

I know this is the way we write in embedded c programming. But is this the right way to write in C#?

Comment: Your timeout mechanism will not work as expected. You should only increment your timer when you really did not receive data and reset it when data was received. In the current implementation your timeout will occur even if you did receive 100 byte.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be interested in handling data coming from the serial port using an event handler.  In the .net `SerialPort` class, you can register an event handler for data received:

```
var sp = new SerialPort("COM1") {
    BaudRate = 9600,
    Parity = Parity.None,
    StopBits = StopBits.One,
    DataBits = 8,
    Handshake = Handshake.None
};

sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
```

You can also set the `ReceivedBytesThreshold` property on the `SerialPort`, which determines when your event handler will get fired.

Then, you just set up your event handler to read data and do what you need with it:

```
private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string data = sp.ReadExisting();
}
```

Using this type of pattern, you don't have to loop, you just set the threshold you need, and let the framework call your event handler when the serial port's got that many bytes ready for you.

Hopefully that helps and I haven't missed your point completely.  :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @hmqcnoesy. But seems like using your way will receive all the data no matter what. How do I do data filtering using your way? I just need the data in between 0x01 and 0x04, others is just rubbish.

Comment: @Coolguy Well you can set the `ReceivedBytesThreshold` to 1.  Then your event handler will fire with each byte that hits the serial port.  Then you can have the filtering logic in that event handler.

Comment: Noted. I've tried you suggestion. But why when I typed in sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler); there's an error. There's 3 error involving this line. 1.Invalid token '+=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration. 2.Method must have a return type. 3.Identifier expected

Comment: Hmmm.  The easy way to add an event handler in Visual Studio is to type the `sp.DataReceived +=` then hit tab twice and it will make sure everything is wired up correctly (it makes the event handler method for you even).  You might try that and see if it works better.  Maybe my example code is just messed up somehow.

Comment: I'm on a mac right now, but I will take a look tomorrow at the example code I wrote to see where I made a mistake.  Can't tell what might be wrong at this point. :(

Comment: Noted. I've edited my question. What I actually need is a timeout. How do we usually do timeout in C#?

Comment: I've added sp.ReadTimeout = 1000 into my coding. Somehow it worked by popping out an error stating "The operation has timed out" after I do not receive any data. Do you guys think this is the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

`ReadByte` is a synchronous call. It will only return when there is a byte read.

To have your attempt getting to work you can check for available data before reading:

```
if(sp.BytesToRead > 0)
{
    Data = sp.ReadByte();
}
```

Besides that I prefer asynchronous reading as [hmqcnoesy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11856932/128886) suggested.